# A way to dynamically save files in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, file, save

I want to be able to save variables to disk sometimes. And I want to save it in a subfolder called '_WorkData'.

The bellow code works fine as a stand alone code

```
OutputName = 'my favorite file';
save(['_WorkData/' OutputName '.mat'], 'foobar');
```

However as a function it cant find the variable `Variable 'foobar' not found.`

```
function noDataReturn = saveFileDisk(name,variable)

    save(['_WorkData/' name '.mat'], variable);

    noDataReturn = 'file saved';

end
```

I can see why this happens but I'm not familair enough with matlab code to understand how to correct it.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: @Schorsch So did you downvote this because of a typo? That's not helping me!

Comment: Who said I downvoted? Rather, see my answer below.

Comment: Not sure I would call this a duplicate after comparing the linked question and answer to this. It seems far easier to understand and read, even if the content overlaps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a three-fold problem.

1. You have to pass the variable to your function (and not the string)
2. However, the save call actually needs the string
3. The function has to have a variable with the original name to save it as intended.

Here's how it works:

```
function noDataReturn = saveFileDisk(name,variable)

    savename = sprintf('%s',inputname(2));

    S.(savename) = variable;

    save(['_WorkData/' name '.mat'], '-struct', 'S', savename);

    noDataReturn = 'file saved';

end
```

You obtain the original variable name using the [`inputname`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/inputname.html) function (in this case, the second input is what you are after).
Next, you need to create a [`struct`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/struct.html) with a field name corresponding to your original variable name.
With this, you can utilize the [`save`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/save.html) function's option to save fields from a `struct` individually.
Now, when you call

```
saveFileDisk('test_name',foobar)
```

the result will be a variable `foobar` in your `test_name.mat`-file.

Comment: Brilliant solution. Wouldn't have found it without my current knowledge.

Comment: You're welcome. Was a tough one. I liked it.